# Selecting columns in a table

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select a range of columns within my Data Table.
Have only got this far:

```
Sub ColumnTEST()
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MAIN_DATA").DataBodyRange.Select
End Sub
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use `Select`.  See [How to avoid using Select in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Edited your title so you are not SHOUTING at us.

Comment: Just record a macro and follow that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the column range reference by index or name.

btw, `Select` is not necessary in most case.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MAIN_DATA").DataBodyRange.Select
' Get the column by index
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MAIN_DATA").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Select
' Get the column by name
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MAIN_DATA").ListColumns("Column2").DataBodyRange.Select
' Column 4 to 7
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MAIN_DATA").ListObjects(1).ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange.Resize(, 4).Select
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [ListObject.ListColumns property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.listcolumns?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm734086)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: Thanks taller. 
I tried the column by name but got error 'Subscript out of range'. 
The 'Get column by index' works perfectly. 

What if I wanted to choose column 4 through to  column 7? 
I have tried adding it in with the index type e.g. ListColumns(4, 7) but the results in an error reading "Wrong number of arguments or invalide property assignment" ??
Have also tried writing the two lines of code but it only results in selecting the later of the two (Column7).

Comment: Please change `Column2` to the column name of your table. I have added the code for  `choose column 4 through to column 7`.